# White Screen on Xcode simulator

Tags: swift, segue

When I run the code, only white screen is shown,
the problem I encounter is **Thread 1: "[<BMI_Calculator.CalcualteViewController 0x7f97856099a0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key calculateButtonLabel."** inside the AppDelegate.swift file.

The starting project is here: https://github.com/appbrewery/BMI-Calculator-iOS13

My code for the CalculateViewController(which is the first one):

```
import UIKit

class CalcualteViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var heightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var heightSlider: UISlider!
    @IBOutlet weak var weightSlider: UISlider!
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }
    
   var bmiValue = "0.0"

    @IBAction func heightSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let height = String(format: "%.2f", sender.value)
        heightLabel.text = "\(height)m"
    }
    
    @IBAction func weightSliderChanged(_ sender: UISlider) {
        let weight = String(format: "%.0f", sender.value)
        weightLabel.text = "\(weight)Kg"
    }
    
    @IBAction func calculatePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
        let height = heightSlider.value
        let weight = weightSlider.value
        
        var bmi = weight / (pow(height, 2))
        
        bmiValue = String(format: "%.1f", bmi)
        
        performSegue(withIdentifier: "goToResult", sender: self)
    }
    
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if segue.identifier == "goToResult"{
            let destinationVC = segue.destination as! ResultViewController
            destinationVC.bmiValue = bmiValue
    }
    /*
    // MARK: - Navigation

    // In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        // Get the new view controller using segue.destination.
        // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
    }
    */

}
}
```

My code for the ResultViewController(which is the second one):

```
import UIKit

class ResultViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var bmiLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet weak var adviceLabel: UILabel!
    
    var bmiValue: String?
    
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        
    }
    @IBAction func recalculateButton(_ sender: UIButton) {
        self.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your codebase, potentially a xib file or a storyboard, you have a reference to `calculateButtonLabel` that isn't linked to anything. My best guess is that you used to have an IBOutlet linked to it that no longer exist.

The GitHub repo you linked doesn't contain a reference to `calculateButtonLabel` and it builds & runs fine in the simulator (Xcode 12.1).